# sql creating table from columns in other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 4 tables called table1, table2, table3, table4. Each has a column in it called x,y,z, and w respectively:

```
x               y               z                w
---          ------          ------            ----
1             A               120               Red
2             B                33.3             Orange
3             C                81.3              Green
4             D                 41.3              Blue
```

I would like to create a new table that simply has it its columns, just these columns where the order of the rows are unchanged. In R(), I would just do something like data.frame(x,y,z,w), but, I don't know how to do something equivalent in SQL Server 2016. The tables have no common key (except their row number of course!).

Comment: Hi @AkashKC what do you mean?

Comment: SQL tables are modeled after unordered sets of records.  You will need at least a second column in each of the four tables which provides the ordering we are seeing right now.  With that in place, a join would then become feasible.

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen they are already in the correct ordering, i.e., by row number.

Comment: No, row number _requires_ a column to generate the numbers.  You don't have one.  Your data model is broken, and SQL is a bit different than R.

Comment: You at least need a column that says row number

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this:

```
WITH CTE_Table1 AS (
SELECT x, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS x_row
FROM Table1
), CTE_Table2 AS (
SELECT y, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS y_row
FROM Table2
), CTE_Table3 AS (
SELECT z, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS z_row
FROM Table3
), CTE_Table4 AS (
SELECT w, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS w_row
FROM Table4
)
SELECT x, y, z, w
FROM CTE_Table1
INNER JOIN CTE_Table2 ON CTE_Table1.x_row = CTE_Table2.y_row
INNER JOIN CTE_Table3 ON CTE_Table1.x_row = CTE_Table3.z_row
INNER JOIN CTE_Table4 ON CTE_Table1.x_row = CTE_Table4.w_row
```

Comment: This will change the column order at least for `z` and `w` and he wants to maintain the current order of the dataset. As noted in the comments `row_number()` needs a column to order by and those tables doesn't have one.

Comment: @AlbertoMartinez You were right, I edited my answer, no it should preserve the row order of original data